# Validar campo em Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, formulário, validação, uitextfield

Cenário:

Ao preencher um formulário, deve ser verificado se um dos campos foram preenchidos de maneira correta, contendo 6 números seguidos de duas iniciais que são os estados do Brasil.

Não se trata de e-mail e nem campo de senha, apenas um campo simples.

Como pode ser feita esta verificação ?

Exemplo: 123456RJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando apenas expressão regular, você pode ter um método assim:

```
- (BOOL)validarCampo {
    NSString *string = [self.campoQualquer text];
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"^\\d{6}(SP|MG|RJ)$" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];

    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Ficaria extenso alí onde você completa com o restante das siglas de todos os estados.

Caso contrário, para esta validação dos estados você pode ter um `NSArray` simples e depois validar por fora os dois últimos caracteres. Mas desta forma com expressão regular já funciona da forma que você precisa.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste!!

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente!! Obrigado!!!